# Two XMLHttpRequest in a row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was wondering if I could have a page `index.php` that sends a Javascript `var idToken` and in the page `token.php`  it will recieve the `var idToken` via javascript then in this `token.php` page I will have more code that result in other variables and i want to send that variables to the third page using a `XMLHttpRequest` so that in my `data.php` I will store data in my database via `PHP` but i also want to show data to user in the origin page `index.php` so I'm printing data that I recieve via `POST` in my `data.php`.
How can I print data from `data.php` to `index.php`

Comment: do you want to display the stored data to the user in index.php ?

Comment: Yes, @Vigikaran for the user to see the data

Comment: in that case you can store the data in session at data.php page and display it on index.php if the session variables are set.

Comment: That's a good way of thinking, thanks @Vigikaran .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

in data.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['stored_data'] = "some value";
?>
```

and in index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['stored_data'])
{
echo $_SESSION['stored_data'];
/* you can unset session if you dont want the data to be displayed anymore*/
}

?>
```